Error Deploying Nginx on Docker: Mounting Path Issue with Nginx.conf
I am trying to deploy nginx on docker container, I received this error:
unable to start container process: error during container init: error mounting "/data/compose/158/docker/nginx/nginx.conf" to rootfs at "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf": mount /data/compose/158/docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf (via /proc/self/fd/6), flags: 0x5001: not a directory: unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type.

here is the content of docker-compose.yml
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: superset_nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "81:81"
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro

Confirmed that the file ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf exists in the project directory.
Verified that the path is correct relative to the docker-compose.yml file. Project files and dics are like:
project
-docker
--nginx
---nginx.conf
-docker-compose.yml

What could be causing this error, and how do I fix it? Is there a mismatch between the expected file type and the host path?

Is Redis required to reproduce that? Is nginx even required, or does an even simpler container image give the same results? IOW, is this a [mcve]? Does one of https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=error+mounting+to+rootfs answer your question?

@UlrichEckhardt i edited my question and removed Redis. it is related to nginx. other question couldn't asnswer my question.

Is it important to set the container_name field? IOW, is this a minimal reproducible example? Note: We can go on with this still a bit...

Make sure that the file you're trying to mount (./docker/nginx/nginx.conf) is actually a file and not a directory. The error you're seeing typically occurs when there’s a mismatch between the type of the source and destination in your volume mount. Docker is expecting a file at /etc/nginx/nginx.conf inside the container, but it might be receiving a directory instead.
The volume mount you’re using:
./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro

This is a bind mount, which allows you to link a specific file or directory from your host system to a file or directory inside the container. In your case, Docker expects the source (./docker/nginx/nginx.conf) to be a file, and the target (/etc/nginx/nginx.conf) should also be a file, not a directory.

Check if the source is a file: Run this command to confirm that nginx.conf is a file and not a directory by using ls -l ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf
Verify the path: Ensure that the file path is correct and that the file exists at the specified location.
Manual Creation : Create the nginx.conf file using
touch ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf and put some content on it an empty file may cause error too

